# Access A-Frame element from three.js object3D

Tags: three.js, aframe

From A-Frame, you can access an entity's object3D with `.object3D` or `.getObject3D()`, is there a way to do the reverse, when you are working with three.js objects, to get the element an object belongs to? Perhaps adding the parent element to `userdata`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A-Frame attaches the entity to `object3D` as `.el`.

For example with an entity with a mesh:

```
document.querySelector('a-entity').getObject3D('mesh').el;
```

It also attaches to the group `object3D`:

```
document.querySelector('a-entity').object3D.el;
```

This is done during `setObject3D()`.

For `object3D`s that A-Frame does not directly manage and does not have a direct associated A-Frame entity, then we can walk up the scene graph to find the closest one with `object3D.traverseAncestors`.

Comment: Not all entities have a mesh but you can always do `document.querySelector('a-entity').object3D.el`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function that traverses upwards using traverseAncenstors and returns an element if there is one.

```
function getParentEl( o ){
  let p;
  o.traverseAncestors( function( a ){
    if( p === undefined && a.el ){
      p = a;
    }
  });
  if( p ){
    return p.el
  }
  return;
}
```